# JPA: Composite key mapping with common field as primary key

Tags: jpa

I have two table with composite keys which shares a common column as part of their composite key. Below is by ER:
Table A: schemaId,aID
Table B: schemaId,bID,aID

Here scheId is contant value.
A and B has OneToMany relation(i.e., A record has multiple B records)

When I form a ManyToOne relation in Table B, I am doing below:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "aID", referencedColumnName = "aID")
@JoinColumn(name = "schemaId", referencedColumnName = "schemaId")
private A a;
```

Above works fine(records get inserted), but I require schemaId as part of Entity B as there are other table which share this composite key from Table B.

In order to maintain the filed in entity if I change @JoinColumn with (insert="false" update="false"), value is passing as null for schemaId as it will treat as optional one.

```
Entity A:
@IdClass(APK.class)
@Entity
public class A
{
   @Id
   private Integer schemaId;

   @Id
   private Integer aId;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "a")
   private List<B> blist;
...
}

public class APK implements Serializable{
   private Integer schemaId;

   private Integer aId;
}

Entity B:
@IdClass(BPK.class)
@Entity
public class B
{
   @Id
   private Integer schemaId;

   @Id
   private Integer bId;

  private Integer aId;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "aID", referencedColumnName = "aID")
@JoinColumn(name = "schemaId", referencedColumnName = "schemaId")
private A a;
}

public class APK implements Serializable{
   private Integer schemaId;
   private Integer bId;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried marking your schemaId Id mapping with the column annotation and mark it as insertable=false, updatable=false instead of marking the join column read-only? If your provider doesn't accept it, the only alternative is to manually set the schemaId value when you set the 'a' reference

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It is adding one more column to insert script which is giving index issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - marking the schemaId ID as read-only still has your provider writing it out? maybe show it in the question. Otherwise, just set the Schema value in B as you do for A when creating B.